# jQuery's fadeOut and callback - two elements shows up when action is made fast

Tags: jquery

It's simple problem, but I can't seem to solve it. I have this code, it pretty much explains itself:

```
    $('div.userrate').hover(function() {
        var width = $(this).width();
        $(this).width(width);
        $(this).stop().children('form').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).next('p.hidden').fadeIn('fast')
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('p.hidden').stop().fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).prev('form').fadeIn('fast')
        })
    })
```

It works great, but when I go fast through all the elements, it breaks. Both `p.hidden` and `form` are visible. I tried to add `stop()` to some actions here, but it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

-- edit --

As requested, HTML for .userrate:

```
<div class="userrate">    
<form>    
<input class="star {split: 2}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="1">    
<input class="star {split: 2}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="2">    
<input class="star {split: 2}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="3">    
<input class="star {split: 2}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="4">    
<input class="star {split: 2}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="5">    
<input class="star {split: 2}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="6">    
<input class="star {split: 2}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="7">    
<input class="star {split: 2}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="8">    
<input class="star {split: 2}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="9" checked="checked">    
<input class="star {split: 2}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="10">
</form>    
<p class="hidden">Skończyłem</p>    
</div>
```

Comment: Go ahead and put your html here too.

Comment: Okay, it's there. Please note, that those inputs are converted by star rating plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Easiest thing would be to</strike> add `.stop()` to the callback fades as well.
Changing `.fadeIn()` to `.fadeTo()` should ensure the rating element is always faded all the way in (which the the problem  was getting). Never had a problem with the `.hidden` element not fading out properly (which makes sense) but you could use `.fadeTo()` there in case.

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36SCH/

Comment: Seems to be working good, but try going through it fast a couple of times. It freezes and not reverting to form.

Comment: I solved the problem with your striked answer :) Adding `.stop()` before every `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` did the trick.

Comment: Glad it's working for you. Those `.stop()`s are definitely needed, the `.fadeTo()`was just to counter an issue I noticed where the form could get stuck at 50% opacity. If you don't need it, brilliant! :)